# How to apply ranking for values across groups not within the group itself

Tags: python, pandas

suppose that I have this dataframe

```
    date        id
0   2019-10-01  303
1   2019-10-01  303
2   2019-10-01  404
3   2019-10-01  404
4   2019-10-02  303
5   2019-10-02  303
6   2019-10-02  404
7   2019-10-02  404
```

I want to apply ranking so that I have this dataframe

```
    date        id   id_rank
0   2019-10-01  303  1
1   2019-10-01  303  1
2   2019-10-01  404  1
3   2019-10-01  404  1
4   2019-10-02  303  2
5   2019-10-02  303  2
6   2019-10-02  404  2
7   2019-10-02  404  2
```

I tried `pandas.groupby.rank()` with this code

```
df["id_rank"] = df.groupby(["index_date", "id"])["id"].rank(method="first")
```

which gets me closer to the wanted result

```
    date        id   id_rank
0   2019-10-01  303  1
1   2019-10-01  303  1
2   2019-10-01  404  1
3   2019-10-01  404  1
4   2019-10-02  303  1
5   2019-10-02  303  1
6   2019-10-02  404  1
7   2019-10-02  404  1
```

I want to rank based on date. If the id is registered in the dataframe for the first day, it takes rank 1 and if it's registered again on the second day, it takes rank 2 and so on; rank 3 if the id is registered on a third day

Comment: Can you explain your ranking logic? Everything with the same date has the same rank?

Comment: @lummers I want to rank based on date. If the id is registered in the dataframe for the first day, it takes rank 1 and if it's registered again on the second day, it takes rank 2 and so on; rank 3 if the id is registered on a third day

Comment: It's still not clear to me. In your example, you have `id` `303` with an `id_rank` of 1  on 10/01 and with a `id_rank` of 2 on 10/02. Why do all the `ids` not share the same `id_rank`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranking logic is not entirely clear. There are two ways it can be interpreted: (a) everything with the same date has the same rank or (b) the dates are ranked per id. Given the name `id_rank` I assume that it is the second option.

1. If the ranking logic is (a), you can simply write

   ```
   df["id_rank"] = df.date.rank(method="dense").astype("int")
   ```

   The `method="dense"` argument results in the ranking per unique value, rather than an index to the sorted results as the normal `rank()` function returns.
2. If the ranking logic is (b), you can use a similar idea as in the first method, but you first group by the `id` before ranking:

   ```
   df["id_rank"] = df.groupby("id").date.rank(method="dense").astype("int")
   ```

To illustrate the difference, suppose you instead have the dataframe

```
         date   id
0  2019-10-01  303
1  2019-10-01  404
2  2019-10-01  404
3  2019-10-02  303
4  2019-10-02  404
5  2019-10-02  405
6  2019-10-03  404
7  2019-10-03  405
```

Then the result given by the two different options would be:

```
        date   id  option_a  option_b
0 2019-10-01  303         1         1
1 2019-10-01  404         1         1
2 2019-10-01  404         1         1
3 2019-10-02  303         2         2
4 2019-10-02  404         2         2
5 2019-10-02  405         2         1
6 2019-10-03  404         3         3
7 2019-10-03  405         3         2
```

The key difference being whether the ranks for id `405` starts at 1 or 2.